# View doesnt navigate in real ipad device but works fine in emulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

In a button click I am navigating the view to another xib which works fine in real iphone device, ipad iphone both emulators but not in real ipad. Here is my code :

```
-(IBAction)cardAnimation{
ViewController_ipad *view = [[ViewController_ipad alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
}
```

but one thing to be noticed that I have done `NSLog` in my destination class's viewdidload method and surprisingly that thing is being logged though that view is not being loaded at all by the above code. What can be the problem?

Comment: first: you may try to delete the app on your device and run it again

Comment: facing same problem....button click is not performing on iPad with iOS 5.1.1

Comment: Check and make sure self.navigationController is not nil.

Comment: If these things are problems then why it is working in real iphone and emulators?

Comment: What do you see? No change in the view? A black screen?

Comment: at this moment i dont have access to that ipad, i will test it soon, if you could give me a generalized common solution which should work then I could test that also, thanks :)

Comment: self.navigationController is not nil @bbodayle

Comment: I see no change in the view, just logs are showed which logs are created in the viewdidload method of the destination class @rdelmar

Comment: iOs simulator manages files more lightly, e.g. it doesn't remove files from app bundle until the app is completely removed. If there was no xib `ViewController_ipad` referenced at the project, the app would crash on device, still the files might not be the same or something. In order to make sure bundle state is valid, try to remove the app from simulator and reinstall it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a MainWindow~ipad.xib file that is referenced through your AppDelegate and you also tried to alloc the Window in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in your AppDelegate file. For which there might be some problem occurred. Whenever you are trying to push your navigation controller, it is actually pushing, but not showing the next controller may be because of the Window over that controller.

It might solve your problem:

**Go to your Project settings (not through File->Project Settings) by clicking on your Project at the left panel/navigator -> select your TARGET and go to Summary Tab -> scroll down to iPad deployment Info -> there you'll find the Main Interface option -> remove the name "MainWindow_iPad" and left it empty and save it. Run the application in your iPad and it will work fine.**

Best of luck. :-)

N.B: Don't forget to clean your build and remove the application from your device before you go for the new build.

Comment: Thanks vaia, ami pearlyar friend :)

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone simulator is **case-*insensitive*** for file names. The devices are **case- *sensitive***. Check to make sure that your nib name isn't actually `Viewcontroller_ipad` or `ViewController_iPad` or another variation. This behavior once got me trying to use an image file in my app - it would work in the Simulator, not on device.

Answer (score 0):

Try a fresh install (deleting the app), and if you are building from xcode hold Option and go to Product - > Clean Build Folder

Also are you naming your nibs with ~iphone and ~ipad?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, i had problem with my iPad (iOS 5.1.1).

When i was pressing button but that was not responding.

That is because of i added `UIGestureRecognizer` on `self.view`.

I solved this problem by **adding gestureRecognizer on my button.** (its just trick not an proper solution, Just implement it if you did not find any other way.)